# Filter a list using User().FullName?

Tags: sharepoint, filtering, powerapps

I'm new to PowerApps and I'm currently working on a basic app that lets employees edit their own record from a SharePoint list which is only populated by a few managers.
PowerApps has already generated a basic CRUD application providing me with a BrowseScreen, DetailScreen and an EditScreen.

The issue I'm having is that I needed the gallery to show only the current user's records. I tried using

```
SortByColumns(Filter('Employee List', StartsWith(ComplianceAssetId, User().FullName)), "ComplianceAssetId", If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))
```

But it doesn't seem to work due to "delegation issues" which I am not familiar with. I found a possible solution [here](https://olafd.wordpress.com/2016/10/09/filter-data-by-the-current-user-in-powerapps/) but from how I understand it, it's checking for Author.Name which is not my case as the list is only populated by managers. I have a field in the list called 'Full Name'.

Any form of assistance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the delegation issue is because of the use of the User() function in the filter argument.  I suggest you replace with a variable as suggested here:
[Cache current user](http://baizini-it.com/blog/index.php/2017/08/29/powerapps-user-function-cache-current-user-onstart/)
This will also improve app performance.
Then your filter expression should be this:

```
SortByColumns(Filter('Employee List', StartsWith(ComplianceAssetId, CurrentUser.FullName)), "ComplianceAssetId", If(SortDescending1, Descending, Ascending))
```

Comment: Thanks! It didn't work at first so I directly assigned User().FullName to CurrentUser and that did the trick!